# Chrome Extension - How to pass variables from JS to popup.html?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have some variables in the following JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (){
    document.getElementById('btn4').addEventListener('click', getbg);
});

getbg = function()

{

    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(
        function (bg) {
        var allcompanynames = bg.companynames;
        alert(allcompanynames)})

}
```

As you can see, the variable is "allcompanynames".

However, how do I pass them and show it on the popup.html page?

I have tried

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="companynames.js"></script>
<p id="allcompanynames"></p>
```

no luck. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (){
document.getElementById('btn4').addEventListener('click', getbg);
});

getbg = function()

{

chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(
    function (bg) {
    var allcompanynames = bg.companynames;
    alert(allcompanynames)})
    document.getElementById("allcompanynames").innerHTML(allcompanynames)

}
```

I'm guessing you should add that last line after displaying the pop up to add the content into the page.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code in this way

```
var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage(); 
     var allcompanynames = background.companynames;
alert(allcompanynames)
```